# Can gcloud nodejs modules see each other?

Tags: node.js, gcloud-node

I'm developing a application that runs client js code inside the node server (not safe, i know).

I use [node vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), although It seems safe, I want to isolate it in another module so even though some malicious code reads all my node server code and config, it don't see important files.

I was reading https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuration-files but i'm not sure it serves my purpose.

Example:

Files:

- < app>/notsafemodule/app.yml
- < app>/notsafemodule/...
- < app>/safemodule/app.yml
- < app>/safemodule/secret.txt

Are (safemodule) and (notsafemodule) deployed in same container?

Is it possible that (notsafemodule) can read (< app>/safemodule/secret.txt)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modules/services are deployed in different instances with different URLs:

- safemodule-dot-< app>.appspot.com
- notsafemodule-dot-< app>.appspot.com

So it's not possible that they see each other..